# useEffect running on every render even when dependency is unchanged

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am using Firebase auth in a React app. I am getting the error below:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already 
>   exists (app/duplicate-app).

I am trying to configure and initialise a Firebase app to make use of the Firebase auth SDK. Using React class base components worked without any errors, but moving over to React Hooks is proving a challenge.

A simple example of where the problem is occurring:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';

const App = () => {

  const [emailVal, setEmailVal] = useState('')
  const [passwordVal, setPasswordVal] = useState('')

  const handleChangeEmail = (event) => {
    setEmailVal(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleChangePassword = (event) =>{
    setPasswordVal(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const auth = firebase.auth()
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailVal, passwordVal)
      .then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
      });
  }

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };

  console.log(firebaseConfig)

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("useEffect called")
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }, [firebaseConfig])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing client side authentication</h1>

        <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Email:
            <input type="text" value={emailVal} onChange={handleChangeEmail} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Password:
            <input type="text"  value={passwordVal} onChange={handleChangePassword}/>
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I place a console.log in useEffect it appears that the useEffect hook runs after the first render, which is good. Then when I type into the text input boxes and the component is re-rendered, the useEffect hook runs again, even though the firebaseConfig variable is unchanged. I suspect that each re-render is actually creating a new version of the firebaseConfig variable that in turn triggers the useEffect hook.
To overcome this I removed the dependency from the useEffect hook like so:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("useEffect called")
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }, [])
```

This works well, but I am getting linting warnings:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'firebaseConfig'. Either 
>   include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

So my next step was to set the firebaseConfig in a useState call. But then I also get linting warnings that the setFirebaseConfig is not being used.

I would comfortably leave the dependencies empty so that that useEffect works like ComponentDidMount but then the linting warnings concern me that I may be causing a problem in my code.

Essentially, if I could somehow compare the actual values in the firebaseConfig and add that to the useEffect dependency I think it would work as the values themselves are unchanging once the app is loaded. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: try to instead of putting config into your own object put it in `state`.

Comment: Thanks Maielo, that is a workable solution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every render a new `firebaseConfig` object is created which cause the `useEffect` to run again.

You can move `firebaseConfig` outside your component.

Or you can use `useMemo` hook so that the `firebaseConfig` is not created every render, like this :

```
const firebaseConfig = useMemo(() => ({
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}), []);
```

Comment: Great stuff Mohamed. It works and no linting issues. Thanks! I shall add useMemo to my toolbox for future use.